# Spring kafka multiple consumers result combination

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have producer which produces some messages(10 for example).
There are n partitions and a consumer group with n consumers.
Kafka system will distribute the messages among the consumers.
How do I combine the messages of all the consumers in one place so that I have 10 messages.
I am using Kafka with Spring.

Comment: `How do I combine the messages of all the consumers in one place so that I have 10 messages` what do you mean by this? are you trying save this data somewhere?

Comment: Actually i want to have the complete data for downstream processing.

Comment: If you have consumers of same group then you will get all the data in downstream

Answer (score 0):

Create a consumer group with only one consumer, then you will get the records from all the partitions in one place.